# How do you consolidate repeated code within functions?

Tags: php, function, oop, while-loop, dry

I tried to create a class to consolidate the following functions but I don't fully understand the approach, how would I approach the following functions to remove the need to query the DB on each occasion an just call the separate echo blocks?

```
function get_pages_new() {
$cxn    = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'northern') or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
$query = ("SELECT * FROM `pages` ORDER BY `page_id` ASC") or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
$getnews = mysqli_query($cxn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getnews)) {
    $page_id        = $row['page_id'];
    $page_title     = $row['page_title'];
    $admin          = $row['admin_only'];

    echo "<li><a href="."add_page.php?page_id=".$page_id.">$page_title</li></a>";
}
};

function get_pages_edit() {
$cxn    = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'northern') or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
$query = ("SELECT * FROM `pages` ORDER BY `page_id` ASC") or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
$getnews = mysqli_query($cxn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getnews)) {
    $page_id        = $row['page_id'];
    $page_title     = $row['page_title'];
    $admin          = $row['admin_only'];

    echo "<li><a href="."edit_page.php?page_id=".$page_id.">$page_title</li>   </a>";
}
};

function get_pages_delete() {
$cxn    = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'northern') or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
$query = ("SELECT * FROM `pages` ORDER BY `page_id` ASC") or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
$getnews = mysqli_query($cxn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getnews)) {
    $page_id        = $row['page_id'];
    $page_title     = $row['page_title'];
    $admin          = $row['admin_only'];

    echo "<li><a href="."delete_page.php?page_id=".$page_id.">$page_title</li></a>";
}
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in a parameter that contains the link:

```
    function get_pages($link) {
           $cxn    = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'northern') or  die(mysqli_error($cxn));
           $query = ("SELECT * FROM `pages` ORDER BY `page_id` ASC") or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
           $getnews = mysqli_query($cxn, $query);

           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getnews)) {
                 $page_id        = $row['page_id'];
                 $page_title     = $row['page_title'];
                 $admin          = $row['admin_only'];

                 echo "<li><a href='".$link."?page_id=".$page_id."'>".$page_title."</li></a>";
            }
    };
```

Where $link is add_page.php, edit_page.php or remove_page.php. Unless I've misread your code and each function is running a seperate query, this should work :)

Answer (score 1):

$Create a method for that instead of a class:

```
function extractIdTitleAdminFromEntry($entry) {
  return [
    'page_id'    => $entry['page_id'],
    'page_title' => $entry['page_title'],
    'admin_only' => $entry['admin_only'],
  ];
}
```

Now you can do this inside your while loops:

```
list($page_id, $page_title, $admin_only) = extractIdTitleAdminFromEntry($row);
```

You can even modify it such that the list of properties is dynamic:

```
function extractIdTitleAdminFromEntry($entry, $properties) {
  $values = [$key];
  foreach ($properties as $key) {
    $values[$key] = isset($entry[$key] ? $entry[$key] : null;
  }
  return $values;
}

list($page_id, $page_title, $admin_only) = extractIdTitleAdminFromEntry(
  $row, 
  ['page_id', 'page_title', 'admin_only']
);
```